# Why cloud firestore has been deleted?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have accidentally changed the app name (property) in pubspec.yaml as well as the android:label in the AndroidManifest.xml file, and after deploying my app My cloud Firestore database has been deleted, but my uploaded images are still in the storage.

Why this is happened? My google-services.json is still the same

How can I retrieve my old database?

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firestore data does not simply get "deleted" by running or publishing a new app.  Something has to actually run code to delete documents.  Since we can't see what changed, nor do we have any clue as to what could have deleted documents, there's not much that can be said.  In the console, you should make sure you are actually looking at the correct project.

Firestore has no ability to revert or restore lost data.  There is only an [import/export mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) that you can use manually.

Comment: My app will only delete the document, only when the user manually hit the delete button on the specified document, it is simply a daily expenses app, the last image of the last transaction is still there, but my database is gone, when I click on Cloud Firestore, it shows to create the database (as if there is no database has been created before)

Comment: If you think there's a problem with the Firestore service or the console, contact Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow is for coding question, and there's unfortunately no code for us to look at.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support